# Extracting the second occurrence in the following string

Tags: regex, r, gsub

Consider the following strings with the expected output.

```
"NE-390-SM-04"                 --> "390-SM-04"
"90055-SL-01-J"                --> "90055-SL-01"
"NE-1478-SL-02"                --> "1478-SL-02"
"87007-QM-01-J"                --> "87007-QM-01"
"NE-9315-BM-01-A"              --> "9315-BM-01"
"3121-SP-01"                   --> "3121-SP-01" 
"1639-YL-01"                   --> "1639-YL-01"
"NE-9922-WM-01-J"              --> "9922-WM-01"
"ND-2498-YL-01"                --> "2498-YL-01"
"C-4008-PP-03-J"               --> "4008-PP-03"
"876-C-4008-PP-03-J-234"       --> "4008-PP-03"
```

Is there a way to extract the occurrence(especially the second occurrence) of 
`[0-9]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+` in R?

I was able to reference the parts using the regex: `([0-9]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+)`
I am interested in the most central part matching the above pattern.

Hope i have made it clear. Please let me know if you need any clarifications.

Comment: Try `sub("^.*?\\b([0-9]+-[a-zA-Z]+-[0-9]+).*", "\\1", s)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a lazy dot matching pattern at the start and a greedy dot matching pattern at the end, and use a capturing group with the backreference to it in the replacement pattern, *and* make sure the number of letters in the middle is at least 2 with the limiting quantifier `{2,}`:

```
x <- c("NE-390-SM-04", "90055-SL-01-J", "NE-1478-SL-02", "87007-QM-01-J", "NE-9315-BM-01-A", "3121-SP-01", "1639-YL-01", "NE-9922-WM-01-J", "ND-2498-YL-01", "C-4008-PP-03-J", "876-C-4008-PP-03-J-234")
sub("^.*?([0-9]+-[a-zA-Z]{2,}-[0-9]+).*", "\\1", x)
```

See the [R demo](https://ideone.com/gr0ixg) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xA8kU1/1).

**Pattern details**:

- `^.*?` - Start of the string and zero or more chars as few as possible
- `([0-9]+-[a-zA-Z]{2,}-[0-9]+)` - your pattern matching 1+ digits, hyphen, 2+ letters, hyphen, 1+ digits
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the end of string.

If you do not use `{2,}` with the letter matching subpattern, you'd get `876-C-4008` in the last `876-C-4008-PP-03-J-234`.

Comment: Thank you so much for such a detailed explanation Wiktor. I appreciate it.